# How to save file to sd card

Tags: android, file-io

I'm kinda new to android and java programming, can someone tell me how to save the files, I have the following codes:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream( location + "/zipSample.zip");
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

try {
    ZipEntry ze;
    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int count;
        while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        String filename = ze.getName();
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

        // Do something with 'filename' and 'bytes' ...
        // How do I save to sdcard?
    }
} finally {
    zis.close();
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 9):

**FileDemo2.java:**

```
package com.javasamples;

import java.io.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class FileDemo2 extends Activity {
    // GUI controls
    EditText txtData;
    Button btnWriteSDFile;
    Button btnReadSDFile;
    Button btnClearScreen;
    Button btnClose;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // bind GUI elements with local controls
    txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    txtData.setHint("Enter some lines of data here...");

    btnWriteSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWriteSDFile);
    btnWriteSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }// onClick
    }); // btnWriteSDFile

        btnReadSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadSDFile);
        btnReadSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // write on SD card file data in the text box
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            String aBuffer = "";
            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
            }
            txtData.setText(aBuffer);
            myReader.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Done reading SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }// onClick
        }); // btnReadSDFile

        btnClearScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearScreen);
        btnClearScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // clear text box
                txtData.setText("");
            }
        }); // btnClearScreen

        btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // clear text box
                finish();
            }
        }); // btnClose

    }// onCreate

}// AndSDcard
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget28"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff0000ff"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtData"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="180px"
android:textSize="18sp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnWriteSDFile"
android:layout_width="143px"
android:layout_height="44px"
android:text="1. Write SD File"  />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnClearScreen"
android:layout_width="141px"
android:layout_height="42px"
android:text="2. Clear Screen"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnReadSDFile"
android:layout_width="140px"
android:layout_height="42px"
android:text="3. Read SD File"  />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnClose"
android:layout_width="141px"
android:layout_height="43px"
android:text="4. Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is a great answer, thank you! I would add a subfolder in save: File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/"); storagePath.mkdirs(); File myFile = new File(storagePath, "mysdfile.txt");