# How to save recorded video in custom folder in android

Tags: android, video-recording

How to save a video in a custom folder and not in default folder so this is my code ,but when i switch off recording it just hangs

```
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/FutureCopyright");
            if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                // do something here
            } else {
                // create dir here
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            System.out.println(1);
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            System.out.println(2);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,"video/3gp");
            System.out.println(3);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,6000);
            System.out.println(4);
            ff=new File(SDCARD_ROOT_PATH + SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD,VIDEO_CAPTURE_NAME);
            System.out.println(5);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile((ff)));
            System.out.println(6);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Comment: also add SDCARD_ROOT_PATH,SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD and VIDEO_CAPTURE_NAME varaibles values with question. make sure u have added SDCARD permission in Manifast file

Comment: yes i have added that in mainfest file

Comment: public final String SDCARD_ROOT_PATH = Environment
   .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 public final String SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD = "/FutureCopyright/";
 public final String IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME = "imgtemp"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gp";

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674249/android-how-to-save-file-to-sd-card

Comment: yes 
but its not up to the mark

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.for saving file you can refer this link.

```
 public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html