# How to create a text file while doing android automation using Robotium

Tags: robotium

I am working on Robotium automation, my requirement is to create a text file or pdf file which contains some assertion report. But I can't generate the report using rock-bottom. Even I tried system. Out. println which is not printed in the console.

Please help me, How to approach it?

Thanks
Manikandan

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to see print lines from Android. You can use [logging](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to put messages to logCat. You can also save file for instance on sd-card (you will need permission in your manifest). Those links should help you with that:

- [How to save file to sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674249/android-how-to-save-file-to-sd-card)
- [Writing a file to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455102/writing-a-file-to-sdcard)

Comment: maszter, Thank you for your valuable Idea, let try it.